How to turn off "Codeium: Edit (Ctrl + l)" from popping up in Visual Studio Code?
When I highlight code I'm working on in VS I get this:

The "Codeium: Edit (Ctrl + l)" appears at top and I don't want it to.
It's from Codeium, but does anyone know how to disable it from popping up?
Thanks
I've tried messing with the settings in VS code, messing with the extension settings, and looking online.

Found the answer. It is with "Code Lens" in the settings. Disabling Code Lens in VS Code settings will stop the pop up from Codeium
